# Get elements data from json file

Tags: android

I have a format file .json below:

```json
{
  "FeatureFlipping": {
    "NFCFeature": {
      "Enabled": {
        "polaris": true,
        "default": false
      }
    },
    "ForceTransitFeature": {
      "Enabled": {
        "ParkDetroit": true,
        "default": false
      }
    }
  },
  "SpecificValues": {
    "MapCustomZoomLevelFeature": {
      "MPLS": 100,
      "default": null
    },
    "DefaultUSState": {
                                                                                                               
      "MPLS": "MN - Minnesota",
      "Pensacola": "FL - Florida",
      "default": null
    },
    "DefaultFPSCountry": {
      "default": "FR"
    }
  }
}
```

How to Can I get all FeatureFlipping element and SpecificValues element ?
Any suggestion, Tks!

Comment: Try looking at [Android - How to Read and Write (parse) data from JSON File?](https://medium.com/@nayantala259/android-how-to-read-and-write-parse-data-from-json-file-226f821e957a)